# Array is passed as an argument in function and accessed,So Why does the values of array gets modified after returning from function?

Tags: c++, arrays

Why arr[0] in main function produce different output unlike arr[0] in user defined function in my code?Why arr[0] in main function giving output 5?

I have tried understanding it through pointers but still not getting.

```
void fun(int a[]){
a=a+1;
cout<<a[0]<<" ";}
int main(){
int arr[3]={5,10,15};
fun(arr);
cout<<arr[0]<<" ";
cout<<arr[1]<<" ";
return 0;}

I expect output to be 10 10 15,but the actual output is 10 5 10
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Why do you expect the output to be different?

Comment: Did you mean `*a = *(a+1);`? The expression `a=a+1;` is functionally equivalent to `a=&(a[1]);`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think he expects the change in `a` to also change `arr`.

Comment: It seems like you might be trying to reduce the size of `arr` in `fun` by "dropping" the first element. Arrays cannot be resized in c++. You would need to first pass the array by reference, but then there would still be no way to "move" `arr` to the second element.

Comment: No It is a=a+1;

Comment: `a=a+1` increases the pointer value of 4, because `sizeof(int)` is 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code creates the array: `a[0]=5, a[1]=10, a[2]=15`. When you call `fun(arr)` it passes in the array (a pointer to the array which is a pointer to the first value in the array: 5). In fun the "`a=a+1`" moves the pointer to point at the second value the array: 10. Printing a[0] prints out 10 because that is what the array points to. The values in the array itself are not changed. When you return you print out a[0] and a[1] where are 5 and 10. In main the array variable a has not moved.

Comment: when a is passed means the address of first element is passed So why it is not reflecting in main function?

Comment: In main there is a variable called "arr" that has a value. When "fun(arr)" is called a copy of the value is passed to the function. In the function the copy of the variable (now called a) is changed. This does not change the value that is in main. If you passed a pointer to the variable to fun then you could change the value of the variable used in main.

Answer (score 1):

In your function `a` is a pointer. In your program `a` points to the first element of `arr`. You increment `a` so now it points to the second element of `arr`. So far so straightforward.

But the change in `a` has no effect at all on `arr`. `arr` is still an array of three elements and nothing that happens in `fun` changes that.

Comment: when a is passed means the address of first element is passed So why it is not reflecting in main function?

Comment: @YashMehta Because that's how C++ works. If you pass a **value** to a function then any changes to that value only happen inside the function. It's different if you pass a **reference** but there are no references in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Note: We cannot have parameter of array types since arrays are not copied. Parameter of array types automatically get converted to pointer. That doesn't mean array types always get converted to pointer types. Based on the context, array types "sometimes" get converted to pointer types implicitly. C++ primer book has some really good examples on this topic:

```
// despite appearances, these three 
// declarations of print are equivalent
// each function has a single
// parameter   of type const int*

void print(const int*);

void print(const int[]); 

// shows the intent that the function 
 // takes an array

void print(const int[10]); 

// dimension for documentation
 //purposes (at best)
```

When you do `a = a + 1;` you are actually advancing the array pointer inside fun function's local scope. Arrays are not copied in function argument. So only array pointer will be "copied". However, the local array pointer will be a distinct pointer that will point to the same object. You then advance that pointer which makes no impact to your actual array pointer. I think you are lacking knowledge about pointer arithmetic, and implicit pointer convertion  behaviors of built-in arrays.

`int arr [n];` gets implicitly converted to `int *arr;`. Note that size `n` inside subscript is actually part of  declaration for built-in arrays. Built in arrays implicitly create pointer to the first element. Then you say `a= a +1;` This is equivalent to saying your "local copy" of array pointer to point to `arr[1]`.  You do all these inside fun function's pointer, which is a copy of your actual passed argument, and it is itself a distinct pointer. Any changes to that pointer has no impact to actual array pointer object as you intended.

You can `*arr = *arr + 5;` or `arr[0] = arr[0] + 5;` to actually add 5 to your first element to make it 10.

Comment: [Arrays are not pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer). `arr` is not a pointer.

Comment: No they are not. But built-in arrays get "implicitly" converted to pointer in most cases. I'd refer to "C++ primer" chapter 3.5 for more details.

Comment: So then Why in main function arr[0] is 5 and not 10

Comment: This is irrelevant to main function's scope. The pointer was advanced within the local scope of fun function. This will impact only the cout inside fun function's scope.

Comment: Arrays are not copied in a function parameter argument. Only array pointer is "copied". A copy makes another distinct pointer inside the fun function's scope that points to same object. Any changes to that pointer is the change only to the local copy. The only exception could have been if the parameter was passed by reference.

Comment: @RafsanMobasher That's true, but my comment was because the statement *" `int arr [n];` is actually `int *arr;`"* is incorrect and propagates the myth that arrays are pointers.

Comment: Ok I see your point. I should have said "implicitly converted" rather than " is actually". Arrays are not pointers but built-in arrays really do get implicitly converted to pointers